# Could not execute build using Gradle upon Creation of Liferay Module Project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, liferay

I was trying to do the liferay sample project in this [link](https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/writing-your-first-liferay-application) but I encountered a problem in doing it. It prompts the error message below.

[image]

I tried the solution I found in this [link](https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/92375325) but still encounters the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I hope you have created Liferay module workspace first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a network issue to me. Are you perhaps behind a proxy?
In that case you should include the settings for your proxied connection in your gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=YOUR_PROXY_HOST
systemProp.http.proxyPort=YOUR_PROXY_PORT
systemProp.https.proxyHost=YOUR_PROXY_HOST
systemProp.https.proxyPort=YOUR_PROXY_PORT
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Though as per checking, there's no existing proxy settings in my machine.